# Swipe doesn't work properly in a uiscrollview

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, swipe

I have an `UISrollView` called `templateView`. I must add to it a swipe gesture to allow the user to swipe left/right to see another templates. The problem is that most of times the user can't swipe easily because the view scrolls down/up instead of swiping to another view. his finger needs to be aligned strictly horizontal to swipe to another page and this isn't acceptable from a user experience perspective.

Any idea how to handle such cases? Is there a way to implement an angle for detecting the swipe gesture? or, is there a way to do it as a custom uigesture for detecting oblique lines with a specific angle?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to implement UIGestureRecognizer Delegate method. This method is called when recognition of a gesture by either gestureRecognizer or otherGestureRecognizer would block the other gesture recognizer from recognizing its gesture. Note that returning YES is guaranteed to allow simultaneous recognition.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
    shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer  
    {
        return YES;
    }
```

**Reference:** [UIGestureRecognizer Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizer%3ashouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer%3a)

Do not forget to assign delegate, when you are initializing your swipe gesture.

**UPDATE 1** CREATING YOUR OWN GESTURE

You always can subclass UIGestureRecognizer class and implement `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, `touchesEnded` methods - manually managing the states of the gesture depending on your own needs.

I am posting some sample code of implementing custom EdgeGestureRecognizer for your better understanding.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    UITouch *touch = touches.anyObject;
    CGPoint location = [touches.anyObject locationInView:self.view];

    // if not single finger, then fail

    if ([touches count] != 1)
    {
        self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
        return;
    }
   //put here some logics for your case. For instance, you can register
   //here your first touch location, it will help
   //you to calculate the angle after.
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

    if (self.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed) return;

    UITouch *touch = touches.anyObject;
    self.previousPoint = self.currentPoint;
    self.previousPointTime = self.currentPointTime;
    self.currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    self.currentPointTime = touch.timestamp;

    if (self.state == UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible)
    {
        CGPoint translate = CGPointMake(self.currentPoint.x - self.startPoint.x, self.currentPoint.y - self.startPoint.y);

        // see if we've moved the necessary minimum distance

        if (sqrt(translate.x * translate.x + translate.y * translate.y) >= self.minimumRecognitionDistance)
        {
            // recognize if the angle is roughly horizontal, otherwise fail

            double angle = atan2(translate.y, translate.x);

            if ([self isAngleCloseEnough:angle])
                self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan;
            else
                self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
        }
    }
    else if (self.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I've already tried it and it didn't improve the swipe functionality. The issue isn't related to recognizing both gestures at the same time because currently they are recognized properly but my request is how to improve it in order to make it more sensitive to the user so he don't encounter any issue while swiping between views.

Comment: There is another way, to construct your template view as another horizontal scroll view with paging enable mode. There are tons of ways, please be more specific in your question. Post some code, post some screen shots and be more detailed in what you want to achieve.

Comment: I think it isn't yet clear enough. Let me back up. The idea is to make the swipe functionality works smoothly inside an UIScrollView. I know that we can support both functionality at the same and it can work properly but the swipe can only work if the finger of the user swipes strictly horizontally. That's my problem. What I'm looking for is a way to enhance this functionality. For instance, I'm trying now to add a diagonal swipe gesture in the UIScrollView. I hope it is clear enough now.

Comment: This is almost what I did. Thanks

Comment: @Maystro, that's why it is strongly recommended post some code that shows what you have done. In that case it is much easier to help you. Happy coding, sir.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me even over a scroll view in swift UI, I was having the same problem where edge swipes didn't work over the scroll view:

```
extension UINavigationController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    }

    public func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return viewControllers.count > 1
    }

    public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Never override a method in an extension. It's undefined behavior. Think about what happens if some other code, such as a 3rd party library, also provided an overridden `viewDidLoad` in an extension. Or what if some other code in the app needs to make itself the `interactivePopGestureRecognizer`?

Comment: @HangarRash then what would you propose the solution be? Taking out *func gestureRecognizer* stops the edge swipes from working above scroll views. This always simultaneous gestures.